# PHP - Is there a way to initialize a class and call a non-static method in one line?

Tags: php, oop

Can someone point me in the correct direction to minimize these two lines of `PHP` into a single line?

```
$foo = new Foo;
$x = $foo->getBar();
```

I've tried the following, but I didn't get my desired result..

```
$x = new Foo()->getBar();
```

Also, this is possible in Yii, using a `CModel` object:

```
$x = Foo::model()->getBar();
```

Is the effect achievable in non-framework PHP without the `model()` static method?

Comment: Why the requirement for one line? Just to make code less readable?

Comment: Not a requirement, just a question.  Readability is subjective, and I find it a waste to clutter the code with a line to initialize an object I only need once.

Comment: It's not possible to call method from new object.

Comment: I'm going to assume that your trying to avoid initializing the object with an extra line of code. With this in mind, my suggestion isn't going to work for a single usage, but if you are trying to eliminate this problem on a large scale, consider using `__autoload`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible from [5.4](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php)

```
$x = (new Foo())->getBar();
```

Comment: I'm curious why this answer was downvoted. It seems to answer the question perfectly. Is there some downside to this technique that we should be aware of?